# mysql : remove row if parent id match in primary key columan

Tags: mysql

Actually, i don't know that what should be the title of the question.

I have two table which schema define as below:

```
**Table 1 (organization_master)**:
CREATE TABLE `organization_master` (  `organization_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  `parent_organization_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  `organization_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,  `c_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
INSERT INTO `organization_master` (`organization_id`, `parent_organization_id`, `organization_name`, `c_user_id`) VALUES
(119, NULL, 'Patel-Apps', 220),
(183, 119, 'Patel-Apps sub 1', 220),
(184, 119, 'Patel-Apps sub 2', 220),
(250, 247, 'Patel-Apps2', 222);
ALTER TABLE `organization_master`  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`organization_id`),  ADD KEY `organization_name` (`organization_name`),  ADD KEY `c_user_id` (`c_user_id`);
ALTER TABLE `organization_master`  MODIFY `organization_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


**Table 2 (organization_assigned_user)** :
CREATE TABLE `organization_assigned_user` (  `organization_assigned_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  `organization_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `organization_assigned_user` (`organization_assigned_user_id`, `organization_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (29, 250, 219),(30, 250, 220);
ALTER TABLE `organization_assigned_user`  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`organization_assigned_user_id`),  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),  ADD KEY `organization_id` (`organization_id`);
ALTER TABLE `organization_assigned_user`  MODIFY `organization_assigned_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=31;
```

when i run below query it give me output as below:

```
SELECT om.organization_id, om.parent_organization_id, om.organization_name FROM `organization_master` AS om LEFT JOIN organization_assigned_user AS oau ON om.organization_id = oau.organization_id WHERE om.c_user_id =220 OR oau.user_id =220 GROUP BY om.organization_id 

organization_id parent_organization_id  organization_name
119             NULL                    Patel-Apps
183             119                     Patel-Apps sub 1
184             119                     Patel-Apps sub 2
250             247                     Patel-Apps2
```

Now, my question is that i don't want the rows which parent_organization_id exists in organization_id column. i.e 199 parent_organization_id  exists in organization_id. so my out put should be like like below.

```
organization_id parent_organization_id  organization_name
119             NULL                    Patel-Apps
250             247                     Patel-Apps2
```

Comment: You can do this with JOINs https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: you should take a look at JOINS

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this

```
SELECT om.organization_id, om.parent_organization_id, om.organization_name
FROM `organization_master` AS om LEFT JOIN organization_assigned_user AS oau 
ON om.organization_id = oau.organization_id 
WHERE om.c_user_id =220 OR oau.user_id =220 
AND Exists (SELECT 1 FROM `organization_master` o 
                     WHERE o.organization_id = om.organization_id 
                     AND o.parent_organization_id <> om.organization_id) 
GROUP BY om.organization_id;
```

Comment: not working. it gives me 4 rows but i need 2 rows as posted in question.